Error: NX Request failed with status code 403
With this command, I installed Nx correctly on my system
npm install -g nx

Then I started my first project with this command
npx create-nx-workspace my-monorepo

I answered almost all the questions that he asked me with the same default answer, only the desired framework was Angular and I used scss for the UI, but I clicked the rest as my default.
Now it gives me this error, what is the problem


please share screenshot of the error, if possible the text of error and stacktrace

Change your IP adders (use Ip mask) .Cause Iran is forbidden. Or use this git repository.(https://github.com/ahmad118128/nx)

The reason is from Iran you can not download packages directly;
with using VPN, your problem will be fixed.
worked for me ;))
